# validate radio button list in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblradio" runat="server">

        <asp:ListItem Value="M" Text="Male"></asp:ListItem>

        <asp:ListItem Value="F" Text="Female"></asp:ListItem>

    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How to validate this radio button list in javascript i am doing like this event if i

selected any option it saying not selected

```
function ValidateAccessLevel() {

        var AccessLevelIndexValue = document.getElementById('<%=rblradio.ClientID%>');

         if (AccessLevelIndexValue.checked)
         {
            return false;

            }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The above code would be simpler as: `return !AccessLevelIndexValue.checked` assuming that this would be the correct way to validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using an ASP RadioButtonList to render your radio buttons, I'd suggest to stick to the ASP framework and use an ASP RequiredFieldValidator to make the radio buttons required.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    id="radioValidator 
    runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="rblradio"
    Display="Dynamic">
    *
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

[How to use requiredfieldvalidator for radio button in aspnet](http://www.itjungles.com/net-controls/how-to-use-requiredfieldvalidator-for-radio-button-in-asp-net)